# Cannot open multiple files with Emacs on Mac

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal

I can open a single file with Emacs, no problem. But I'm used to Emacs on Linux, where typing `emacs test.cpp &` would open a new Emacs frame, leaving the terminal free. On OS X, however, when I try to open a new frame with `emacs test.cpp &`, the terminal shows a process was created but the window fails to pop up. If I push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the terminal shows "Stopped", but I see the process is still running because I can see it in the task monitor.

How to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of emacs are you using? The non-GUI version that comes with OSX (located at `/usr/bin/emacs`), or did you install the GUI version? First you say you call `emacs test.cpp` (this is the non-GUI version), but then you say a window pops up (GUI version).

Comment: `&` is for putting a new process in the background; it has nothing to do with opening zero, one, or many files. To get Emacs back into the foreground, type `fg`. To open multiple files, try `emacs test.cpp test2.cpp test3.cpp`, etc.

Comment: @Juancho I used homebrew to install the GUI version of Emacs (24.4) and also modified the PATH. When I input "which emacs", it shows "/usr/local/bin/emacs", so I assume this version of Emacs is called each time, but I'm not sure. And BTW, I didn't delete the old version with OSX.

Comment: @echristopherson I didn't know this before. I came from Linux. I would use & so that I could open a new window without occupying the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the command `emacs` on Linux is generally just the Emacs binary itself, which opens a new frame (that's Emacs-speak for X11 or other GUI window) *unless* you specify `-nw` on the command line; in contrast, the `emacs` command provided by Homebrew is a shell script that calls `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.3/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw  "$@"` (substituting the version installed for `24.3`). So the Homebrew version launches as a terminal app.

You can make a shell script that just runs `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.3/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@"`, and it would behave somewhat as you expect, except that you would be launching a brand-new instance of the Mac app, which would cause an additional Emacs icon to appear on the Dock. Such a thing isn't considered "Mac-like," but it's not the end of the world.

An alternate solution, which is used a lot across different operating systems, is to make one Emacs process a server and then use `emacsclient` to open files from the command line. Emacsclient can open files in the current terminal, a new frame (GUI window), or an existing instance of Emacs. For an instance of Emacs to run as a server just requires that you run `M-x server-start` within it, or put `(server-start)` inside your init file (~/.emacs or ~/.emacs.d/init.el).

My Emacs config has this snippet, which starts server mode automatically when I launch the GUI app:

```
(when (display-graphic-p)
  (server-start))
```

Then, once Emacs is running (you can make it autostart upon login in System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items), type `emacsclient -nw test.cpp` to open the file in the terminal, or `emacsclient test.cpp &` to open it in an existing frame, or `emacsclient -c test.cpp &` to open a new frame. (Note that if you open it in an existing frame, you use `C-x #` to close the buffer without closing the frame, as opposed to `C-x C-c`.)

Note that the terminal `emacsclient` command I gave just now didn't use `&` but the GUI ones did. `&` at the end of a command line puts the process in the background, meaning it's not monopolizing your terminal. For whatever reason (probably because it wouldn't be sensible to have a full-screen terminal app running in the background), when you invoke the terminal version of Emacs with `&`, it just suspends itself. The same thing would happen if you pressed `C-z` within Emacs. To get it back into the foreground, type `fg` (actually you can have multiple background processes, in which case `fg` would just pick the most recent one unless you specified a *job specifier*; see bash's man page (`man bash`) and search for `JOB CONTROL` if you're interested in the details).

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! It appears I need to get used to this style since I always kill the "server" with C-x C-c.